# Sometime Postgresql Query takes to much time to load Data

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I am using PostgreSQL 13.4 and has intermediate level experience with PostgreSQL.

I have a table which stores reading from a device for each customer. For each customer we receive around ~3,000 data in a day and we store them in to our `usage_data` table as below

[image]

We have the proper indexing in place.

```
  Column     |            Data Type        |     Index name            | Idx Access Type
-------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
 id          | bigint                      |                           | 
 customer_id | bigint                      |  idx_customer_id          | btree
 date        | timestamp                   |  idx_date                 | btree
 usage       | bigint                      |  idx_usage                | btree
 amount      | bigint                      |  idx_amount               | btree
```

Also I have common index on 2 columns which is below.

**CREATE INDEX idx_cust_date
ON public.usage_data USING btree
(customer_id ASC NULLS LAST, date ASC NULLS LAST)**
;

**Problem**

Few weird incidents I have observed.
When I tried to get data for 06/02/2022 for a customer it took almost 20 seconds. It's simple query as below

```
SELECT * FROM usage_data WHERE customer_id =1 AND date = '2022-02-06'
```

The execution plan
[image]

When I execute same query for 15 days then I receive result in 32 milliseconds.

```
SELECT * FROM usage_data WHERE customer_id =1 AND date > '2022-05-15' AND date <= '2022-05-30'
```

The execution plan
[image]

**Tried Solution**

I thought it might be the issue of indexing as for this particular date I am facing this issue.

Hence I dropped all the indexing from the table and recreate it.

But the problem didn't resolve.

**Solution Worked (Not Recommended)**

To solve this I tried another way. Created a new database and restored the old database
I executed the same query in new database and this time it takes 10 milliseconds.

The execution plan
[image]

I don't think this is proper solution for **production server**

Any idea why for any specific data we are facing this issue?
Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Please guide. Thanks

Comment: Query performance questions like this must include `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete query you are running and (slow) the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The EXPLAIN output is added. Please review

Comment: Have you tried providing TIMESTAMP rather than DATE constants in your query? E.g. `SELECT * FROM usage_data WHERE customer_id =1 AND date between '2022-02-06 00:00:00' and '2022-02-06 23:59:59'`

Comment: The execution plan  does not match the query. Is that actually a view? Please add the view definition. Also, don't post SQL or query plans as images, but as formatted text.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yes i have tried

Comment: And what is the result? Is it faster?

Comment: no it was same as previous